# How do I go about a PHP search result page?

Tags: php, mysql, session, echo

I have code for a search function here:

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
   if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {
   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' OR shout LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC ") or die(mysql_error());
   while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
       $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
       $shout = stripslashes($info['shout']);
       //Result code goes here eventually
   }
   }
   ?>
```

and I'll eventually make it display all results in a grid.
My problem starts when a user clicks on an item to see a page devoted to just that item (like any retail store site).
I'm assuming in my search code I can use $_SESSION and just set all the columns to sessions and then echo them on my `results.php` page.

Is this an efficient way to do this or am I going about it wrong?
I see websites that when you click on a certain item the URL looks all crazy and what not and I'm not really sure what causes that.

Comment: No you shouldn't add the results to session (at least in this case). Just add them to an array and print them like you normally would (preferably in a view). Regarding the crazy URLs: you should post an example, I have no idea what you mean ^^

Comment: Hey, from php you are returning an array, try to insert one more variable like $anchorHref=$info['href']; then in your results.php page you can display like <a href="<?php echo $somevar['href']?>">Link Name goes here</a>

Comment: @JimL I mean like this: http://www.staples.com/Xbox-S9G-00005-Xbox-360-Console-250GB-Hard-Drive/product_IM1LC7913 How do I get my URL to do something like that when I click on a search result?

Comment: @user2566387: just add links which will take the user to those kinds of URLs, then just rewrite them. In the case you are proposing you could just take product_IM1LC7913, and from that extract IM1LC7913 which you could fetch from the DB and show in a unique product page.

Comment: @JimL I have a product number column in my DB for each item so I definitely know how to extract the product.  Now, how do I get it into my URL without having a unique HTML page for each result? I'm trying to have one page (result.php or whatever) and when I click on product 100 it goes to domain.com/result/100 or something but it simply edits that one result.php page

Comment: Are you using apache? You can use mod rewrite to automatically rewrite domain.com/result/100 to something like domain.com/result.php?id=100. Then just use $_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
header('Location: /search/'.rawurlencode($search));
exit;
```

and now you can get your search string by

```
$search = rawurldecode($_GET['your_name']);
```

and your first page will not differ from the others. Or you can use method="get" in your search form. Anyway, you can use session to store your search string.

Comment: Where would I put this code? at the top of the results page? Or at the bottom of the search results page?